# Two HTML selects with differing selected values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got following HTML code:

```
<select id="first">
  <option value="0" selected="selected"> default </option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select id="second">
  <option value="0" selected="selected"> default </option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

So both of them have same data. I need to secure, that user can't select same value in both of them.

I hoped, that JQuery has some nice feature like:

```
$("#first").getOptions()
```

or even

```
$("#first").setOptions()
```

but unfortunately, it doesn't. This makes it very complicated for me, because I don't know JQuery very well ...

So, what is the best approach to solve my problem?

Comment: Did you try making select `disabled?`

Comment: when a selection is made in one `<select>` disable the corresponding `<option>` in the other

Comment: Did you mean option? I don't see, what I solve by disabling whole select ...

Comment: if you want to select the options, use `$('#first > option')`

Comment: i suggest before open of select generate options

Comment: Yes! Now I see how to achieve this :)

Comment: I added a codepen example that I created. It should demonstrate the functionality you were looking for. I used jQuery to accomplish this. Also, whoever decided to downvote every other answer, could you please read the answers before you cast a misleading vote, or atleast give a reason as to why you down-voted? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value of the currently selected option by doing:

```
$('#first option:selected').text();
$('#second option:selected').text();
```

Assuming I understand your question, you don't want the user to be able to enter the same value in each box. So, something similar to:

```
$first = $('#first');
$second = $('#second');

$first.on('change', function() {
    $second.find('option').attr('disabled', false);
    var firstVal = $first.find('option:selected').text();
    $second.find('option:contains("'+ firstVal +'")').attr('disabled', true);
});

$second.on('change', function() {
    $first.find('option').attr('disabled', false);
    var secondVal = $second.find('option:selected').text();
    $first.find('option:contains("'+ secondVal +'")').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

I should probably note that there are ways for you to achieve your `getOptions()` and `setOptions()` ideas, you can do `$select.find('option')` to get the options. For setting them, define some options in html and set the `select` element's innerHTML to those elements:

```
var options = '<option value="0" selected="selected"> default </option>
               <option value="1">One</option>
               <option value="2">Two</option>
               <option value="3">Three</option>';

$select.html(options);
```

## JSFiddle demo

Comment: surely you'd want to enable previously disabled selections too? people change their mind

Answer (score 2):

You can [disable](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp) single options in your `select`

```
<select id="second">
  <option value="0" selected="selected"> default </option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" disabled>Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Handle event `onSelect` on first `select` and based on it disable proper `<option>` in second `select`

Comment: and the other way around as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this([codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJGopL)):

**HTML:**

```
<select id="first">
  <option value="0" selected="selected"> default </option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select id="second">
  <option value="0" selected="selected"> default </option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
var strUser;
var strUser2;

$(function() {
    $("#first").change(function() {
      var e = document.getElementById("first");
      strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
      if (strUser == strUser2) {
        alert("Dropdowns contain the same value. Change one.")
      document.getElementById("first").disabled=true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("second").disabled=false;
      }
    });
});

$(function() {
    $("#second").change(function() {
      var e = document.getElementById("second");
      strUser2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
      if (strUser2 == strUser) {
        alert("Dropdowns contain the same value. Change one.")
        document.getElementById("second").disabled=true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("first").disabled=false;
      }
    });
});
```

Essentially, this code will retrieve selected values from the dropdowns on change, and then a comparison will be made. If the values are equal, the recently selected dropdown will be disabled. You then will have to select a different value in the other dropdown to re-enable the disabled dropdown. Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJGopL) that displays the working functionality. This will not allow a user to select two of the same values without a dropdown being disable and turned off.

Answer (score 0):

When one is changed, if the other is the same, you could change it back to default, like this.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#first', function() {
    var firstVal = $('#first').val();
    var secondVal = $('#second').val();
    if (firstVal == secondVal) {
        $('#second').val(0);
    }
});

$(document).on('change', '#second', function() {
    var firstVal = $('#first').val();
    var secondVal = $('#second').val();
    if (firstVal == secondVal) {
        $('#first').val(0);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="first">
  <option value="0" selected="selected"> default </option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select id="second">
  <option value="0" selected="selected"> default </option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Upvoted since this works, as does mine. It's unfortunate for the community that people down-vote working answers that accomplish a task in a different way. Good work.